# is there an ide that displays live variable data?

Tags: php, macos, ide

Is there an IDE that shows live variable data?
For example:

```
$myVar = 5; 
$total = $myVar + 5;    
print $total;
```

So if I were to mouse over `$myvar` on the second line it would show me the value it contains.
This is very helpful on 1000 lines of code.

The only IDE I know that does this is PHPstorm. The problem is they advertise support, but I can't seem to get it to work on the Mac. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Studio if configure correctly does all that and its available on Mac OS X

http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/

Comment: thanks, wow i didnt even think to check out zend studio. do you what they call it with zend? so that i can look it up? thanks

Comment: @Sarmen It's called debugging. You need a debugging component on the server (like XDebug or Zend Debugger) and a client to communicate with it. Eclipsed based IDEs (like Zend Studio) may use either. Others like Netbeans may only support XDebug at the moment.